# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ProductSubcategoryKey'

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to import my CSV file into the MySQL database. However, I am getting mentioned error. It applies to about 70% of my 800 records.
This is an example of the erroneous records.

```
1,"AR-5381",,"Adjustable Race","NA",
2,"BA-8327",,"Bearing Ball","NA",
3,"BE-2349",,"BB Ball Bearing","NA",
4,"BE-2908",,"Headset Ball Bearings","NA",
5,"BL-2036",,"Blade","NA",
6,"CA-5965",,"LL Crankarm","Black",
7,"CA-6738",,"ML Crankarm","Black",
8,"CA-7457",,"HL Crankarm","Black",
9,"CB-2903",,"Chainring Bolts","Silver",
10,"CN-6137",,"Chainring Nut","Silver",
```

And here is the structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product](
    [ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductAlternateKey] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [ProductSubcategoryKey] [int] NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

They all have this field as ,, . However, it is not a string and NULL value is allowed, so I don't understand where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the data into the database? The problem here is that it reads the third column as empty string, which of course is not valid for an integer column. So in your case, you should tell whatever program you use for importing to not import this column at all or change it to `null`.

Comment: I have tried to use MySQL workbench import wizard and this piece of code:LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'/home/tomek/Dokumenty/SampleDB/Product/Product_data.csv'
INTO TABLE Product  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with that tool but did you try to set the respective column values to null?